# data type (model) was displayed as (data type (model when using "direction:rtl"

Tags: css

I encounter a problem failing to format the parenthesis when using style="direction: rtl;

```html
    <ul style="direction: rtl; ">
        <li>data type (model)</li>
        <li>try another data type (model)</li>
    </ul>
```

It displayed as:

[image]

I add css `white-space:nowrap`,which not the solution.

Comment: Since Firefox and IE display this the way we would expect, I think it's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use should use the left-to-right mark: `&lrm;` after the parentheses so that the text is read left to right. https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html

```html
    <ul style="direction: rtl; ">
        <li>data type (model)&lrm;</li>
        <li>try another data type (model)&lrm; </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Or, if you don't want to pollute the contents of the li with extra stuff, put the lrm in the `::after` using css. https://jsfiddle.net/e26Lg1xh/2/